# how to copy "Pre" tag data to clipboard using typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to create copy button which perform copy data from "Pre" tag using "typescript". I am creating like this but not working appropriately.

I also refer many site where they mention we can't copy data from pre tag. is this right.? if not then how we can resolve ?

```
<button onclick="copyText('text_element')" class="btn button" style="color:black;background-color: #f8f9fa;">Copy</button>



public copyText(elementId){
  let selBox = document.getElementById("pre");
  selBox.setAttribute("value",document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);
  document.body.appendChild(selBox);
  selBox.focus();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(selBox);
  alert("Copied the text: "); 
  }

    <pre id="text_element">
       ............some text-----------
    </pre>
```

Comment: What's the relevance of Aurelia here? It's a JavaScript/typescript question

Comment: @Benny actually I am creating Aurelia typescript application.So i added mistakenly Aurelia.